# How can i force the first item in listview to be hidden

Tags: flutter, dart, listview

i have listView contains many items like following

```
  Scaffold(
    backgroundColor:Colors.blue
    appbar:AppBar()
    body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[    
          Text('hello'),    
          Divider(height: 2, color: Colors.black,),    
          Text('hello'),  
          Divider(height: 2, color: Colors.black,),    
          Text('hello'),  
          Divider(height: 2, color: Colors.black,),    
          Text('hello'),,   
        ],
      ),
     )
```

Now i need to hide the first index or make it not visible or being under appbar or top of screen that not be shown until if user scroll down such as normal scrolling ..

i tried the following but it will not show again if user scroll down . i covered it by Stack and tricked it with container the same Scaffold color

```
  Stack(
      children[
       Text('hello'),  
       Container(
        color:Colors.blue
       )
      ]
     )
```

i know it is not good way at all . because it will be hidden forever

How can i handle it , thanks

Comment: You can check`index` of first item in list. If `index == 0` or `.first`, item won't show.

Comment: Or you can use `listview.builder`, in `itemCount` you set `list.length - 1`

Comment: thanks but i need it to be covered under appbar or whatever it

Comment: `hello` widget will be visible on scroll, and should it stay under the appBar rest of time?

Comment: hello Yasin yes exactly .. i need it such as normal elements but the first index being up a bit like -15 top padding or hidden under appbar,, and if user scroll down  so it will be visible .. please chick Jinto Joseph Answer , he is very near but the problem is that the first element will be forever hidden even if user scroll down it will not be shown

Comment: or in other word : i need  the whole listView like -15 padding top as default .. -15 it is enough to make first element hidden under screen or appBar for example .. and when user scroll down so  it will be walk down normal like others elements

Comment: please check my edited Answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to achieve this  , if you want hind first element under the app bar . please check my code

```
 var itemCount = 31; // change this value to view different result
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('hi'),
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Stack(children: [
          Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          ),
          Positioned(
              top: itemCount <= 20 ? -15 : null,
              right: 0,
              child: Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child: ListView.builder(
                 padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 70),
                  controller: ScrollController(
                      initialScrollOffset: itemCount < 31 ? itemCount + 1 : 31),
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: itemCount,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return Column(
                      children: [
                        Container(child: Text('hello $index')),
                        Divider(
                          height: 2,
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                        Text(''),
                      ],
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ))
        ])));
```

it will work , please change the   `var itemCount = 31 ;` value to view the result

use `flutter_screenutil` plugin . so it will adaptive for all screen size

```
Note That

my device display height: 756.0
my device display width : 360.0
my device display aspectRatio : 0.47619047619047616

so my ScrollOffset should be 31 , so i am use this value
```

Comment: it is very close , i test your code but the first element will be hidden for ever even if i scroll down it will not be visible

Comment: hi ... please check my new code , i am editing this code , in  this way it can achieve it , await 10 second

Comment: please comment , if you have any issue in this code

Comment: i already use flutter_screenutil .. and yes your code is fit my case as well .. wow thanks a lot

Comment: It my pleasure . glad to hear that reply